# Adding part of Java 6 Library to Java 5 Environment

Tags: java, xml, java-6, java-5

I have a situation where I need to use javax.xml library and majority of this comes from Java 6.
However my deployment server runs on Java 5, where I don't have control.

So is it possible to add these specific libraries to project and can run in Java 5 environment?

I am mainly using

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
```

code which I am using

```
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("input.xml");
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
    while(xsr.hasNext()) {
        if(xsr.isStartElement() && xsr.getLocalName().equals("StandardError")) {
            break;
        }
        xsr.next();
    }
```

So can any one tell how can I avoid this so that My application can run in Java 5 environment without issues.

Between we use maven for building, so any libraries has to go into pom.xml

Comment: Doesn't that lot originate from [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)** and [**StAX (JSR-173)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=173) were introduced in [**Java EE 5**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/javaee5-jsp-135162.html) and are completely compatible with Java SE 5 (The version of the JDK when those specs were released).  Of course implementations of these standards were included as part of Java SE 6.

**java.net Repository**

You can obtain the public APIs for the standards from the java.net repository

```
    <repository>
        <id>java.net</id>
        <name>java.net Maven Repository</name>
        <url>https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository</url>
    </repository>
```

Below is the dependency for the latest version of the JAXB public APIs

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Implementations**

In addition to the public APIs you will need to implementations.  Each spec has multiple implementations.  Below is a link to a POM file that pulls in [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as the JAXB implementation (Note:  I'm the MOXy lead).

- https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20120418/blob/master/pom.xml

**About Java SE 5**

Java SE 5 hasn't received any public updates since October 2009, even Java SE 6 is rapidly approaching the end of life.  If possible I would recommend using Java SE 7 (and Java SE 8 is currently in development).

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html